# Invalid Variant Operation when comparing an OleVariant to UnAssigned

Tags: delphi, variant

This is my code:

```
**if** FWordApp = UnAssigned **then**
    FWordApp := CreateOleObject('Word.Application') ;
Result := FWordApp;
```

The above sits in a GETter for a property of type OleVariant.

The first time, it goes through fine, compares TRUE to Unassigned.
However, the same isn't true the second time, where comparing to UnAssigned gives me an Invalid Variant Operation error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message is telling you, you are not allowed to compare `Unassigned` against a COM object in the context of an `OleVariant`. That's an illegal comparison.

Your test should instead use `VarIsEmpty`:

```
if VarIsEmpty(FWordApp) then
  FWordApp := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
```