# OLE automation: How to check if a variant references an automation object

Tags: delphi, powerpoint, ole, delphi-5, ole-automation

I would like to know how can i determine, whether a variant is referencing an OLE automation object, or not.

I'm exporting some Excel graphs to Powerpoint.

I have this code:

```
var PptFile: Variant;

....

// PptFile _might_ be initialized:

PptFile:=pptApp.Presentations.Open(pptFilename);

// It depends on whether the export has items which need to be exported to 
// Powerpoint or not

....

// I would like to determine if PptFile does reference an OLE automated object or not
PptFile.SaveAs(excelFileName+'.pptx');
```

I know, it could be done by placing the last line of the code (with saveAs) between `try...except...end`, but i don't feel that approach is good enough.

I was reading about `VarIsEmpty`, `VarIsEmptyParam`, [Nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577894/checking-for-the-variant-value-nothing), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533890/invalid-variant-operation-when-comparing-an-olevariant-to-unassigned), but i'm not sure about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [`VarIsClear`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Variants.VarIsClear) for this test.

> Indicates whether the specified variant has an undefined value.
>   VarIsClear returns true if the given variant's value is undefined. The
>   value can be undefined for any of several reasons:
>
> - The Variant may have had its value set to Unassigned.
> - The Variant's value may be an interface type that has been set to nil (Delphi) or NULL (C++).
> - The Variant may be a custom variant that returns true from its IsClear method.
>
> In all other cases, the function result is false.
>
> **Note**: Do not confuse an unassigned variant with a Null variant. A Null variant is still assigned, but has the value Null. Unlike
>   unassigned variants, Null variants can be used in expressions and can
>   be converted to other types of variants.

---

However, I question whether or not it is needed. How could it be that `PptFile` was not assigned? That can only happen if the call to `pptApp.Presentations.Open()` fails, and that would raise an exception. Or am I mis-understanding this? I cannot at the present see any scenario in which you could reach the call to `PptFile.SaveAs()` for which `PptFile` had not been assigned.

Comment: It seems, that my Delphi 5 doesn't have a `VarIsClear` function.

Comment: Then you might roll your own. The code reads something like this: `Result := (VType = varEmpty) or
                (((VType = varDispatch) or (VType = varUnknown)) and
                  (VDispatch = nil))`  Now, what about my final paragraph? Do you really need to perform this check?

Comment: Thank you. I will accept this answer, as it has everything (even more than that) i need. `PptFile` is not assigned when there are no charts to export. I know, it's sloppy coding (not written by me, i just need to add something to it and this issue stays in my way). I might end up with counting the exported charts, and if the count is zero, skip this `PptFile.SaveAs(...)`. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: If you just want to detect that you have never assigned a value, use VarIsEmpty. Surely that's in D5.

Comment: I took VarIsClear from the FPC runtime library, and it works out of the box. Thank you.